# Get JSON value from PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, function, neo4j

All, I have got a JSON response from NEO4J:

```
Array
(
    [columns] => Array
        (
            [0] => n
        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [outgoing_relationships] => http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1/relationships/out
                            [labels] => http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1/labels
                            [data] => Array
                                (
                                    [position] => Developer
                                    [awesome] => 1
                                    [name] => Michael
                                    [children] => 3
                                )

                            [traverse] => http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1/traverse/{returnType}
                            [all_typed_relationships] => http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}
                            [property] => http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1/properties/{key}
                            [self] => http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1
                            [properties] => http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1/properties
                            [outgoing_typed_relationships] => http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}
                            [incoming_relationships] => http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1/relationships/in
                            [extensions] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [create_relationship] => http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1/relationships
                            [paged_traverse] => http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}
                            [all_relationships] => http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1/relationships/all
                            [incoming_typed_relationships] => http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I do not know how to retrieve the value "position" under the data array, because the array is under another array.
Can you tell me how to do it with PHP?
Thx

Comment: Why not `$arr['data'][0][0]['data']['position']`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Access them like this.

```
echo $yourarr['data'][0][0]['data']['position'];
```

**Tips on how to locate :**

Just locate where is the `position` keyword, Now look up to the array, As you can see the parent of `position` is `data`, think of how you reach from the start 
(**data**)to the destination(**position**) (*like a maze*).

Answer (score 1):

When you have more than 1 record try this

```
foreach($var['data'] as $inside){ //inner 1st stage

  foreach($inside as $index => $main){ //inner 2nd stage

      if($index == 'data'){ //check if index is data

          echo $main['position']; //output position
      }
  }

}
```